# Need help in correcting the painting in my small Swing Code

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

What I want to make the content Pane transparent and that blue strip of normal dark bluecolour.But in the process of making contentPane transparent ,I am also making that strip as dull-coloured (coz that black colour is being painted over it) accidentally.

[image]

How can I correct it?

(Comment out the paint method and notice the change in strip.This is what I want as final result)

Here is the code:

```
class Home extends JFrame
{
    int width=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().width;
    int height=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height;
    public Home()
    {
        super("WiND");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setSize(width,height);
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(new Color(0x0D70E8));
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height/10));
        add(p);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
        LinearGradientPaint p=new LinearGradientPaint(0,0,0,height,new float[]{0f,1f},new Color[]{new Color(0.2498f,0.2498f,0.2498f,0.3f),new Color(0.1598f,0.1598f,0.1598f,0.8f)});
        g2.setPaint(p);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, width,height);
    }
}
```

(I did that the same thing a year back,but now after a year I forgot how I did that)

**EDIT**

I made the changes to the paint() method only according to @Sage.I get the following output
Correct Blue Strip but now the grey translucent background has gone.
[image]

Comment: paint transparent colours first. Then paint opaque colours after.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Instead of painting in a top level container such as `JFrame`, add a `JPanel` & do custom painting in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  Also return a sensible preferred size for the custom component, to assist the layout manager.

Comment: @Cruncher : How can I do that? I suppose the `paint()` will always be called afterwards.

Comment: @InsaneCoder Oh I see what's happening. You're combining having components and custom painting. You should generally never mix the two up

Comment: He is painting after his children are painted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
        LinearGradientPaint p=new LinearGradientPaint(0,0,0,height,new float[]{0f,1f},new Color[]{new Color(0.2498f,0.2498f,0.2498f,0.3f),new Color(0.1598f,0.1598f,0.1598f,0.8f)});
        g2.setPaint(p);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, width,height);
    }
```

When you are painting with `paint()` function you are painting with graphics instance `g` after your child component `panel` is painted. Go to the source of the `super.paint(g)` function and you will see that three subsequent function is being called:

- `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)`: this one paint your component, e,g.:background
- `protected void paintBorder(Graphics g)`: this one paints the border of the component
- `protected void paintChildren(Graphics g)`: This one paints the children of the component in it

So after this `super.paint(g)` call, anything you draw will appear above all the painting made with these three above function: hence above the children components, for your context the `panel` with blue background.

Now, a solution would be:

```
 public void paint(Graphics g)
{

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
                 // note, we are creating a graphics object here for safe painting
            LinearGradientPaint p=new LinearGradientPaint(0,0,0,height,new float[]{0f,1f},new Color[]{new Color(0.2498f,0.2498f,0.2498f,0.3f),new Color(0.1598f,0.1598f,0.1598f,0.8f)});
            g2.setPaint(p);
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, width,height);
            g2.dispose(); // disposing the object which we created 

            super.paint(g);

    }
```

However rather than doing this, you use a class such as `MyCanvas extends JComponent` and override it's `paintComponent(Graphics)` function and draw inside of it. Then you can set an instance of `MyCanvas` as the content pane of `JFrame` using it's `setContentPane(component)` function.

Check out the [**`A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

---

**Edit** A small demo implementation of your use case:

```
class AMyContainer extends JComponent
{

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
                 // note, we are creating a graphics object here for safe painting
            LinearGradientPaint p=new LinearGradientPaint(0, 0, 0, getHeight(),new float[]{0f,1f},new Color[]{new Color(0.2498f,0.2498f,0.2498f,0.3f),new Color(0.1598f,0.1598f,0.1598f,0.8f)});
            g2.setPaint(p);
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2.dispose(); // disposing the object which we created 
    }

}

class Home extends JFrame
{
    int width=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().width;
    int height=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height;
    public Home()
    {
        super("WiND");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setSize(width,height);
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        setUndecorated(true);

        JComponent container = new AMyContainer();
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(container);

        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(new Color(0x0D70E8));
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height/10));
        container.add(p);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Home().setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: @Stage : This gives the dark blue as wanted but now the background becomes totally transparent,which was earlier gray.

Comment: @InsaneCoder, i am still here. just post a SSCCE, so that i understand the current problem and can help you with. When you are done making such example, just put a comment below

Comment: @InsaneCoder, The problem was happening that, when we are painting with `paint(Graphics g)` working with opaque window, will always cause unexpected result, because window's(JFrame's) internal paint mechanism is more complex than other containers. you will understand if you look into the source code. That is why it is always suggested not to override the `paint(Graphics g)` method of a `JFrame`. However, i have put a demo for you. Which includes the suggestion of my answer. You can just copy and paste to see desired output. And this is what we call `SSCCE`